# Can I use Flash for commercial iOS/Android app/game development?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, flash

Since I've been using Flash for a long time, I want to know if it can be be used for commercial grade games or app development?

Answer (score 0):

[You can make iPhone app  with Adobe Flash CS5, even if you are using Windows.](http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-create-iphone-apps-in-flash-cs5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Flash Pro and Flash Builder 4.5.1 support mobile development. Android, ios, Blackberry.

Adobe® Flash® Player runtime Certified devices 
http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/

Comment: What is advantage of using Flash over others?

Comment: Actually, flash is a middle-ware. So you could develop app across platform. Android, IOS, and the others. One code base, Multiple platform. It is very useful for the already been flash developers to migrate the existed apps to mobile platform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need Flash builder 4.5 premium and you can develop apps/games for IOS. android, blackberry.. :) you need to use flex and action script for coding